# Web Application in place of a more traditional UI?

Tags: user-interface, web-applications

I am considering using a web application in place of a traditional UI to control an imaging system.  The UI will allow the user to do things like change settings, upload scripts, start/stop data acquisition, view data, etc... Rather than a monolithic UI that "does everything", an embedded controller would interact with system hardware and control the process, receiving commands from the UI over a local network.

I would probably use a javascript toolkit or perhaps some .Net technology to build the web application.  A few of the advantages I see are:

1. Access UI from any browser.
2. No software to install.
3. Access remotely if necessary.
4. View status/data from multiple computers simultaneously.
5. Modular (separation of concerns)
6. Data as a web service.

A few of my concerns would be:

1. Lack of a comprehensive widget toolkit.
2. Supporting multiple browsers, this may not be as bad as I think now with HTML5.
3. Updating the UI from the server.

My questions are, Is this common?  Is it a bad idea?

If it's really subjective, I understand, however, I just wanted to see if there is an obvious answer, like "DON'T DO IT!!!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common. I do it all the time, particularly for a closed community of users such as you will have.

It might be different if this was a public facing device, but it is not.

You are going to support more devices by saying "you must have an HTML 5 browser" than if you said "You must have a PC" or "You must have a Mac"

In terms of your concerns, I do not see any of them as being an issue.

- It is easier to deploy a UI upgrade once to the imaging controller than many times to all of the client machines.
- There are all of the widgets that you could ever want available for HTML 5 compatible browsers
- You answered your own question about cross browser issues. HTML 5 browsers are free so there is no downside for people to upgrade to them and you have the entire weight of the world wide web pushing them to upgrade to take advantage of what can be done with HTML 5 so users have a big incentive to upgrade.  I do not run into any push back when I require a closed group to use an HTML 5 compatible browser.  And if you want to be kind to those that don't have html 5, you can always use modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea - and there is plenty of examples and ways of doing what you want to do.